# Run local python script from Google Apps Script

Tags: python, google-apps-script, file-transfer

As the title suggests, I'm looking for a way to run local python scripts from the Google Apps Scripts environment. Right now my method is to write a json file from app scripts and save it to a Google Drive directory. The local machine polls the directory via Google Drive File Stream, and runs the necessary code when the file appears in the directory. Not pretty, but it gets the job done. The main concern with this is that File Stream can be fairly latent - could be up to 15 minutes after a file is put in the directory before File Stream catches it and syncs the local machine.

Is anybody aware of other options? I could try re-writing the python code in Apps Script, though the python code relies on a few third party libraries that aren't available in JS. Another idea is setting up a flask server, but that seems like a good bit of work for the return.

Comment: You could poll an Apps Script webapp to determine if the Python script should execute or not. Or use the Drive API directly to search for the target file. Otherwise no, there isn't a way for Google servers to contact a random local machine.

Comment: Yeah I knew that there wasn't a direct way, but was hoping somebody had a more clever approach than mine. I like your idea about using the Drive API to search for files within a Google Drive directory.